# Achieving non-type template parameters with auto in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, non-type

Is there a way one can mimic the [auto deduction in non type template parameters](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html) in C++14?  Similar to how you can mimic unconstrained arguments in C++14 lambdas in C++11 with templated functors?

Comment: "*Similar to how you can mimic unconstrained arguments in C++14 lambdas in C++11 with templated functors?*" That's not similar at all. Generic lambdas *are* template functors. The capability was always there; it's simply a matter of making it easy. `auto` template parameters are like trying to mimic `auto` in pre-C++11; Boost could do it, but only with substantial macro infrastructure.

Comment: "Generic lambdas are template functors" That is what I meant, the feature of having template arguments in lambdas could always be achieved by writing your own functor with a templated operator().  My question is whether the feature of having type deduction in template arguments already exists in C++14 (maybe with one extra level of indirection or something)  I just cant think of a solution

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: no, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of. You can have non-type template parameters of course, but you need to specify the type. The common idiom for that is:

```
template <class T, T Value>
struct X;
```

But you can't instantiate something like `X<3>` with it. The best you can do is introduce a macro to pull out the type for you:

```
#define DECL(expr) decltype(expr), (expr)
X<DECL(3)> x;
```

Which for `3` is obviously silly, but does help a bit when you want to provide something like a function pointer as a non-type template argument.